# Is there a way to call application classes/functions from c# interactive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Since a few weeks i started to develop a c# application. The last time i did something with c# is  8 years ago so i need to re-discover c# and VS.

I'm looking for a way to call/interact with my application from a terminal/command line. I found c# interactive which is basically where i'm looking for except that i cannot interact with my application.

I cannot reach environment variables or call classes from my project. Is there a way how i can achieve this? It would make it easier to test some functions or logic for me. For the people who are familiar with Laravel (PHP), i'm looking for something similar to thinker.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like https://github.com/waf/replay-csharp ?

Comment: Haven't used C# interactive shell, yet but I'd guess you'll need to load the library, import your namespace and then create an instance of the class you want to call methods on. (Static classes/methods are a different story.) Is that what you have tried?

Comment: You might consider writing unit tests, this can be useful both for testing your own code, but also that your understanding of the framework/libraries is correct. When debugging there is the immediate window that uses the current context for variables etc.

Comment: ^^ Though: Rather than going interactive, I'd recommend to use Unit Tests, instead. They will give you _repeatable_ results with one-time effort to set them up. And you can debug into them.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I know about unit tests and this wil defenitely the goal for repeatable testing. Where i'm currently looking for is more about testing/experimenting during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to achieve this.
You can do a richt click on the project in the solution explorer and than click `Initialize interactive with project".

After this i can simply access the project namespace(s).